# Find the extremal of $J[y]=\int_1^2(y'^2+2yy'+y^2) dx $

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have to find the extremal  for the following functional:
$$J[y]=\int_1^2(y'^2+2yy'+y^2) dx     $$ such that $y(1)=1$ and $y(2)$ is arbitrary.

I got it to be equal $e^{x+1}$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $$J[y,y'] = \int_1^2 (y' + y)^2 dx.$$ Clearly this is always non-negative; it can only reach zero if $y' + y = 0$ which gives $y = e^{-x+1}$ (after taking into acct the boundary condition) so it appears you're missing a sign, though that may have just been a typo.

Comment: 'it can only reach zero' can you please explain this line